# Configuring SSL with java

Tags: java, ssl, post, https

I need to sent a POST request on a https url (https://xyz.in). I have a SSL certificate ( cert.cer ) which will be used to send the Request. I donot know how to use that certificate to make a https connection. Can anyone help me who knows how to do it . I am sending request in java

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because after [googling a phrase of the question](https://www.google.es/#q=use+certificate+to+make+a+https+connection+java&safe=active&ssui=on) user didn't make any searching effort.

Comment: NO Please I am totally confused and didn't understand the solutions on google . please I have wasted enough time on this.

Comment: *please I have wasted enough time on this* sorry but I think you didn't... SO is for concrete problems, if you tried, please paste your code, the errors you have, but SO is not for ask people to make your job

Comment: You need to study the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: Will look into it .thanks #JSSE Reference Guide